# Running a script in apache storm

Tags: java, python, apache-storm

Is there a way to simply run a python script in Apache Storm?

I'm trying to figure out how to use storm to run scripts but am having trouble.  It seems like I need to create a Java program to call the script and use it as a bolt but I simply want to send a very basic python script to storm to see if it is possible.

I read that the following command is helpful in sending topologies to storm but am having trouble understanding the syntax and if I am allowed to send any python code to storm or if it needs to have specific syntax.

Can someone clarify whether or not I can submit any python script to storm and if so what the following line of code means.

```
storm shell resources/ python topology.py arg1 arg2
```

When I try to submit a basic python script using the above code i get the following output.

```
956  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Uploading topology jar stormshell8691441.jar to assigned location: /home/scix3/apache/storm/data/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-ae0739f9-7c93-4f00-a02b-c4eceba3b005.jar
966  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location: /home/scix3/apache/storm/data/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-ae0739f9-7c93-4f00-a02b-c4eceba3b005.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "simple.py" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:254)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:319)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
at backtype.storm.util$exec_command_BANG_.invoke(util.clj:386)
at backtype.storm.command.shell_submission$_main.doInvoke(shell_submission.clj:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at backtype.storm.command.shell_submission.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 10 more
```

The exact command I'm using  (possibly incorrect) is `storm shell resources/ simple.py`

simple.py is merely a `print 'Hello, world` script.

I'm using storm version 0.9.4

Comment: Could you post the contents of simple.py and _exactly_ the command you're using? Also a a storm version wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run python on Storm. In fact you can run just about code from just about any language on a storm cluster, its just a matter of implementing [the API](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Using-non-JVM-languages-with-Storm.html).

However, there are some requirements for that to work, and so far as I can tell said requirements are not spelled out in the storm documentation. The fastest path to get up an running would be to take the [splitsentence.py example from the storm source](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/multilang/resources/splitsentence.py) and run with it.

Answer (score 0):

try pyleus (https://github.com/Yelp/pyleus) or streamparse (https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse), i will recommend using pyleus as it is simple.